# How to zoom an element ignoring everything?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I basically have a code, and what I want to do is when it hovers the element will zoom in and ignore all its flow. When I say "ignoring its flow" it is because other elements (e.g. br tag) may block part of its content.

[image: It needs to be like this]
[image: This problem can happen]

This intends to be like a gallery with images.

Comment: Have you tried setting it a higher `z-index`?

Comment: Yes. It don't work, with z-index I can overlay the THREE for example, but not the <br> tag

Comment: can you include a sample of your HTML

Answer (score 2):

You could use the css property `transform: scale(1.5)` to zoom the element. And set the `z-index` of the zoomed element higher to show on top of all elements.

**Working example:**

```css
.zoom {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: transform .1s;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.zoom:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(1.5); 
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom">1</div>
<div class="zoom">2</div>
<div class="zoom">3</div> <br>
<div class="zoom">4</div>
<div class="zoom">5</div>
<div class="zoom">6</div><br>
<div class="zoom">7</div>
<div class="zoom">8</div>
<div class="zoom">9</div>
```

Comment: The zoom works, but the z-index is not enough. Unfortunately, I can't access the other elements style, so I basically need to get the element out of the flow

Comment: you can set the z-index of the zoomed element.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the main container(**not just the element**) has a class called `container`, just add this rule. It will apply a higher `z-index` to anything you hover, not just the element itself, and this should work:

```
.container *:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Here's an example:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  counter-reset: box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: salmon;
  margin: 0px 2px;
  transition: all .5s;
  counter-increment: box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box::after {
  content: counter(box);
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  background-color: steelblue;
}

.container *:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```